# Button on a map image

Tags: android, image, button, dictionary, imageview

I would like to have an activity where I have a simple world map as ImageView, where I could have multiple button in the map such that if I click on them I could be directed to a new activity. e.g. if I click on the location of France I link to a new activity for France etc.

I am rather new to android so I just drop the Button on top of the image, but then when everything is under relative layout I cannot control the position of the button well; in particular when the button becomes small then I can no longer move it around as I wish.

What is a more proper way of doing the same thing? Any kind advice appreciated.

Best,
Eddy

Comment: you can use google maps v2 api to display the map and add custom markers for each location